# How to update nginx in chef server managed environment

Tags: chef, update

I have some servers managed by chef who are running (partly) the same software, e.g. nginx. If nginx has a security issue and there is a new version, what is the best practice to install the new version on all servers?

Comment: If you're using a package manager, you could specify the version of the software and trigger a chef-client run.

Comment: You mean a chef package manager like librarian-chef, and to adjust the version number in the cheffile?

Comment: No, I actually meant to ask whether you've instructed Chef to install nginx through (for instance) yum or compile it from source. `yum_package` supports the definition of software versions. If you've compiled from source, you could check for the software version through the `nginx -v` command and grep for the version you want, only reinstalling nginx if it doesn't match your pattern.

Comment: I am using the offical nginx cookbook https://supermarket.getchef.com/cookbooks/nginx v.1.4.0, nginx not from source.. In this case the have a default version specified `default['nginx']['version'] = "1.2.6"`

Comment: Why not add nginx version as an attribute + download nginx binaries based on that. So, when you want to upgrade, just change the value of attribute and you are ready to upgrade. This will help you to copmare and  backup old data

Comment: @YoLudke Hm, if I look at this recipe: https://github.com/miketheman/nginx/blob/master/recipes/package.rb it appears that it doesn't really do anything with the version (it just installs the latest version and skips it if it's installed). The source installer does seem to have a run state called `nginx_force_recompile` that will reinstall nginx from the source version in `default['nginx']['source']['version']`. You could however change the package recipe, are you using your own repo?

Comment: Yes, I think for nginx the way is to actualize the cookbook.. As far as I see for the other cookbooks (vim, openssh, git and so on), the version is not specified like this.. So apart from nginx, which seems to be a special case, to keep in sync with secutiry updates https://github.com/patdeegan/chef-unattended-upgrades seems to be the recommended way for servers configured by chef